# Create a helper app without Sandboxing

Tags: macos, sandbox

I've found several guides ([here](http://martiancraft.com/blog/2015/01/login-items/), [here](http://rhult.github.io/articles/sandboxed-launch-on-login/), and [here](http://blog.timschroeder.net/2012/07/03/the-launch-at-login-sandbox-project/)) on how to create a helper app to launch a main app on login. However, as my app is not distributed through the App Store, I do NOT want to enable sandboxing, and all of the solutions I've found require both the helper app and the main app to be sandboxed.

Is there any way to create a helper app to launch a main app at login WITHOUT requiring the use of sandboxing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`[NSWorkspace launchApplication:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/launchApplication:) to launch your app from your helper.