# OS X Login helper app thinks app is already running

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsworkspace, nsrunningapplication

I'm working on implementing a helper app to launch a main, [non-sandboxed app upon user login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30580965/create-a-helper-app-without-sandboxing/30581031#30581031).

I want to make sure that, in the event there is already an instance of the app running at login, the helper app does not launch a second instance of the app, and terminates itself appropriately.

When I'm testing this, and looking at Console's output, I do see that my helper app already thinks there is an app instance running, even if there is not. So, the helper app will quit without launching the main app. Does anyone have an idea on why the helper app may think there is an existing app instance, even though there is not?

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"


@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    //Check if we're currently running My App. If we are, just quit the helper app.
    if ([NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.me.myApp"]) {
        NSLog(@"We're running My App already, so we're going to quit.");
    }

    //Otherwise, launch My App, then quit the helper app.
    else {
        [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplication:@"My App"];
    }

    [[NSApplication sharedApplication] terminate:self];
}


@end
```

Comment: Does your helper app have a different bundle ID?

Comment: @SevenBits, Yes, the main app's bundle ID is 'com.me.myApp', and the helper app's bundle ID is 'com.me.myApp-Helper'.

Comment: You could try logging the actual results of `[NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.me.myApp"]`. Also, depending on user preference settings, OS X will try to restore the apps which were running at the last logout time when you next log in. So, it's very possible that it has relaunched your main app automatically. Are you sure it hasn't? Check with Activity Monitor, not the Dock or Command-Tab app switcher, because running apps can be hidden from those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:` will not return `nil`, it will return an empty array, so this comparison always evaluates to YES.
quote from the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSRunningApplication/runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:):

> Return Value
>   An array of NSRunningApplications, or an empty array if no applications match the bundle identifier.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. So, would my check need to be something like this?

if ([NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.me.myApp"] != 0)

Comment: `if ([NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.me.myApp"].count > 0)` or  `if ([[NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.me.myApp"] lastObject])`